# I need help with finding this specific psychology study!

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, rationality, belief

I don't know where I have read this or watched this, but it's about a study which asks its participants (who were established as logical) to **tear the photos of their families in exchange for some money** and they refuse to tear them as if doing that puts the family in harm or something even though there’s nothing logical about it. Tried everything; Google, ChatGPT, books I have read, everything. Literally at my wits end.